# Where are the closure's captured variables stored?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm working on memory intensive application, that should handle out-of-memory situations properly.

I have something like

```
class memory_manager {
    // returns true if slot created (and function is being run)
    // false otherwise
    static bool create_slot(int id, std::function<void (slot&)>); ........
}
```

This class handles, logs, and so on all of the out-of-memory issues, keeps ownership of all of the slots, and drives concurrency.

However, I have unhandled `std::bad_alloc` on following code:

```
slot_data_to_copy dat;

memory_manager::create_slot(100, [&dat](slot& sx) { sx.assign_data(dat); });
```

I assume that the throw is done during capturing the variables. (I'm capturing actually more of them, this is just a sample example)

Where is the closure created?
Can I control it? Or, if I update the manager in a way that it takes parameter, like

```
slot_data_to_copy dat;

memory_manager::create_slot<slot_data_to_copy>
       (100, dat, [](slot& sx, slot_data_to_copy& dat) 
           { sx.assign_data(dat); }
       );
```

is it guaranteed that it doesn't throw at all?

I'm compiling both using Visual C++ on Windows and GCC on Linux, but I observed this behavior only on Windows (on linux, I run out of memory probably somewhere where I can handle it).

EDIT:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function - std::function contains nothrow operators.. I'm probably missing something, but which one is used in this (lambda) situation?

Comment: `I assume that the throw is done during capturing the variables. ` - the lambda is being copied on heap? and, when is it released?

Comment: [expr.prim.lambda]/2 "The evaluation of a lambda-expression results in a prvalue temporary. This temporary is called the *closure object*." The ctor of `std::function` that is used here is `template< class F > function( F f );`, which is *not* `noexcept`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where is the closure created?

A lambda expression creates an object of of an unnamed type that is just a normal functor class. The captured variables are members of that unnamed type.

Your code `memory_manager::create_slot(100, [&dat](slot& sx) { sx.assign_data(dat); });` is essentially the same as:

```
slot_data_to_copy dat;

struct unnamed_lambda_type {
  slot_data_to_copy &dat;

  unnamed_lambda_type(slot_data_to_copy &dat_) : dat(dat_) {}

  void operator() (slot &sx) const {
    sx.assign_data(dat);
  }
};

memory_manager::create_slot(100, unnamed_lambda_type(dat) );
```

> Where is the closure created?

The closure object is just like any other temporary object, generally allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

The closure *is* the lambda; the captured variables are data members of an anonymous struct (this is what a lambda is). Creating your lambda can't throw `bad_alloc`; your error is elsewhere (probably creating the `std::function`, which could be copying the lambda on to the heap).

Sidenote: you are capturing by reference in your lambda; make sure that your `slot_data_to_copy dat` isn't being destroyed by the time the lambda is being called. You should copy it by value or call the lambda immediately.

Comment: Okay, I assumed that the throw is done during capturing variables (if it is done in std::function<> creation, I don't mind). I'd like the std::function to be created on stack, would that be possible?

Comment: The `std::function` is being passed as a parameter so it is already on the stack. `std::function` internally has a pointer to the lambda on the heap (think how `std::vector` can be on the stack but its data is on the heap).

Comment: ad sidenote - the function create_slot doesn't keep the lambda anywhere, so the data cannot be destructed

Comment: `std::function`'s constructor accepts an allocator, so you can control it that way.